# How to override Image.BrowseImage() in Sitecore

Tags: c#, configuration, sitecore, sitecore6

I am looking for a way to override the behaviour of `BrowseImage(ClientPipelineArgs args)` method in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Image` class (Sitecore 6).

This blog post ([Integrate an external media library into Sitecore – Part 2](http://www.thescrewballdivision.com/integrate-an-external-media-library-into-sitecore-%E2%80%93-part-2)) confirms it is possible.

I have created a custom implementation of `Image` class, but can't find where to register it. I did a search on all Sitecore config file in the solution but could not find any references.

I suspect there is a configuration option somewhere in the Core database.

Any ideas on where I might find this?

*Edit: Posted this on Sitecore support.*

Comment: Do you have a custom implementation of the image editor field or just the image template? Do you want the custom image gallery images to be viewed as items in the tree or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

The issue was I set `Assembly` and `Class` field values, but did not clear `Control` field value.

Correct configuration below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a reference to your new type in the following sitecore location:

```
/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Image
```

[image]

You can register your type in the normal way specifying your assembly and class names.